# Noun for additional portion of food

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a noun for an additional portion of food that you take / ask for, when you are done with what you have been served, but still want more.

> I am almost done with my plate, can I have an ________ (addition?)?

Comment: '_Can I have some / Is there any_ more, please' is idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask for a refill, which is more appropriate.
"Can I have a refill? I'm almost done with the noodles!"

Comment: Stereotypes about nacho cheese and ranch dressing notwithstanding, it would sound very strange indeed to ask for a *refill* of anything other than a beverage or condiment in AmE. You might ask for a refill of your coffee or ketchup, but not your soup or your sundae, much less your chicken roast or your chile relleno.

Answer (score 2):

"Serve", "helping" or "seconds" (in order from most formal to least formal)

As in:

- May I please have another serve?
- Can I have another helping?
- Can I have seconds?

("seconds", in this case, is short for "second helping")

When referring to drinks one generally asks for a "refill", but with solid food we ask for a second serve/helping

Comment: 'Serve' in the sense of 'serving' is flagged as an Australian usage in Collins. OP does not add the 'Australian English' requirement.

Comment: "Second helping" would be standard in British English.

Answer (score 0):

In the example sentence I would just use "another".

> I am almost done with my plate, can I have another?

In more general terms, I agree with [Smoke's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/432897/243245).